# How to extract a list of integer numbers from a list with strings and integers?

Tags: python

I do have a list which looks like:

```
a = ['11, 12, 9, 10, 17, 18, 19, \n', '20, 2, 6, 4, 1, 13, 14, 15, \n', '16, 3, 5, 7, 8, 21, 22, 23, \n', '24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, \n', '32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, \n', '40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, \n', '48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, \n', '56, \n']
```

I want to create a list with each integer in it separately with:

```
a = [int(x) for s in a for x in s.split(',')]
```

I can see the error because of \n and ' but cant find a solution, which should be looking like:

```
a = [11, 12, 9, 10, 17, 18, 19, 20, 2, 6, 4, 1, 13, 14, 15, 16, 3, 5, 7, 8, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56]
```

Can someone give some solution in this regard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just [`strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) the unwanted characters:

```
a = [int(x) for s in a for x in s.strip(', \n').split(',')]
```

Answer (score 1):

you could just add `if x != ' \n'` to your list-comprehension:

```
a = [int(x) for s in a for x in s.split(',') if x != ' \n']
```

a more general approach would be this:

```
b = []
for s in a:
    for x in s.split(','):
        try:
            n = int(x)
        except ValueError:
            continue
        b.append(n)
```

Comment: answer is wrong.... as each element of x represents with `space`, like ' 1', '2' ..., what couldn't be converted to int.  Check my answer....

Comment: @Reishin i agree. one **part** of the answer was incorrect. the rest is ok. +1 for you.

Comment: yep, looks fine. +1

Comment: @Reishin `int` knows to ignore whitespaces... `int("   5   \n") == 5`

Comment: @Tomerikoo yep, right.. But the input data looks as following: `[' 1',' 2',' 3',' \n']`, and int(' \n') definitely not working

Answer (score 1):

One liner and generic solution for python3:

```
a = [...]
res = [int(x.strip()) for s in a for x in s.split(',') if x.strip().isnumeric()]
```

Comment: `int(x.strip())` is redundant and can just be `int(x)`

Comment: @Tomerikoo nope, as the sequence contains `\n` without any numbers, so `int` will fail, check OP provided data, and `strip` is required in `if` condition, for proper work of `isnumeric` function

Answer (score 0):

So to me it looks like you have a list of lines. You could just do:

```py
a = [] # line list
ints = [int(i.strip()) for i in ''.join(list).split(',')]
```

Or you tell us how you got the line list

Comment: yes it is a list of lines i got it from a text file with some code. thank you very much the issue is solved.

Comment: Do you need it as a list of lines? You could have used read instead of readlines to get it all as one string

Answer (score 0):

You could use String.replace() the remove the \n s.

```
a = [int(x) for s in a for x in (s.replace(‘, \n’, ‘’)).split(',')]
```

Comment: nope...if there would be something else?  like `\r\n` ?  Not generic..

Comment: Dude hasn’t even given a generic source of the data. Why we have to make everything generic?

Comment: the data sample were provided, and your code not working alongside with weird quotes

Comment: Do you see any \r in the data sample? Or any mention of a possibility of that being there? This is not a college exam buddy.

Comment: so you can shitty code if it is not college exam? lol

Answer (score 0):

using regex

```
import re
a = ['11, 12, 9, 10, 17, 18, 19, \n', '20, 2, 6, 4, 1, 13, 14, 15, \n', '16, 3, 5, 7, 8, 21, 22, 23, \n', '24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, \n', '32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, \n', '40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, \n', '48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, \n', '56, \n']

a = ','.join(a)
res = [int(i) for i in re.findall(r'[0-9]+', a)]
print(res)
# [11, 12, 9, 10, 17, 18, 19, 20, 2, 6, 4, 1, 13, 14, 15, 16, 3, 5, 7, 8, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56]
```

Comment: while it will work...performance wise it is not recommended solution...

Comment: @Reishin actually mine is faster than yours solution

Comment: mine is not for speed, but the way OP were asked. Python not like  additional checks, while handling errors is preferred. Here is comparison, where test3 is perf-wise: https://repl.it/@simca/so-64846499. Try to execute several times and compare min/max